# How to load and save Widerface dataset for ssd network in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, label, jupyter-notebook

I want to load and save Widerface labels for ssd (single shot multibox detector) network in tensorflow, but `wider_face_train_bbx_gt` is so complicated.

How can I save labels for ssd network in tensorflow?

Comment: We could, but we need some more context. I shamefully admit, I've never heard about SSD network, Widerface dataset or associated label saving issues. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: ssd is a kind of convolutional network. you can see it here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.02325.pdf  Widerface is a great dataset for face detection and its available here: http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/WIDERFace/ . Widerface has a text file annotation . i want to load this dataset and prepare it to use in ssd network . I mean this version of ssd that is implemented here by Tensorflow: https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow

Comment: You can load them with TensorPack like I did here: https://gist.github.com/PatWie/a743d2349f388b27ed3ef783919c3882
running this script should give you the images with bounding boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load the dataset, I give you an explanation how to do this in TensorFlow with [TensorPack](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/tensorpack) (just for the data).

First, we need the zip file and the mat file containing the bounding boxes. The following part basically reads directly from the zip file and the mat-file

```
class RawWiderFaceReader(RNGDataFlow):
    """Read images directly from tar file without unpacking
    boxes: left, top, width, height
    """
    def __init__(self, matfile, zipfile):
        super(RawWiderFaceReader, self).__init__()
        self.matfile = matfile
        self.zipfile = zipfile
        self.subset = matfile.split('_')[-1].replace('.mat', '')
        f = sio.loadmat(matfile)
        events = [f['event_list'][i][0][0] for i in range(len(f['event_list']))]
        raw_files = [f['file_list'][i][0] for i in range(len(f['file_list']))]
        raw_bbx = [f['face_bbx_list'][i][0] for i in range(len(f['face_bbx_list']))]

        col_files = []
        for file, bbx in zip(raw_files, raw_bbx):
            for filee, bbxe in zip(file, bbx):
                col_files.append((filee[0][0], bbxe[0]))

        self.col_files2 = []
        for file, bbx in col_files:
            for ev in events:
                if file.startswith(ev.replace('--', '_')):
                    self.col_files2.append((str('WIDER_%s/images/' % self.subset + ev +
                                           '/' + file + '.jpg').encode('ascii', 'ignore'), bbx))
                    break

    def get_data(self):
        with ZipFile(self.zipfile, 'r') as zip_hnd:
            for fn, bbx in self.col_files2:
                buf = zip_hnd.read('%s' % fn)
                yield [buf, bbx]
```

it gives you a generator `get_data()` which returns the jpeg encoded images and bounding-boxes. The way it is stored seems to be complicated because it is a file containing the bounding boxes produced by Matlab.
To draw the bounding boxes, you can use:

```
def draw_rect(img, top, left, bottom, right, rgb, margin=1):
    m = margin
    r, g, b = rgb
    img[top:bottom, left - m:left + m, 0] = r
    img[top:bottom, left - m:left + m, 1] = g
    img[top:bottom, left - m:left + m, 2] = b

    img[top:bottom, right - m:right + m, 0] = r
    img[top:bottom, right - m:right + m, 1] = g
    img[top:bottom, right - m:right + m, 2] = b

    img[top - m:top + m, left:right, 0] = r
    img[top - m:top + m, left:right, 1] = g
    img[top - m:top + m, left:right, 2] = b

    img[bottom - m:bottom + m, left:right, 0] = r
    img[bottom - m:bottom + m, left:right, 1] = g
    img[bottom - m:bottom + m, left:right, 2] = b

    return img
```

The entire script is here:
https://gist.github.com/PatWie/a743d2349f388b27ed3ef783919c3882

After `pip install -U git+https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/tensorpack.git` you can fire it up by

```
python data_sampler.py --zip /scratch/patwie/data/wider_face/WIDER_val.zip \
                       --mat wider_face_split/wider_face_val.mat \
                       --debug
```

To convert it into an lmdb-file you can use the other argument. No need for unzipping the data here.

To use the data, it is like in the script:

```
from tensorpack import *
ds = LMDBDataPoint('/scratch/wieschol/data/wider_face/WIDER_train.lmdb', shuffle=True)
ds = RawWiderFaceReader(matfile=args.mat, zipfile=args.zip)
ds.reset_state()
for jpeg, bbx in ds.get_data():
    rgb = cv2.imdecode(np.asarray(jpeg), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Comment: Thank's . I did all of them but in your entire script I was a little confuse. What's my wrong here ?
  `parser.add_argument('--lmdb', 'C:/Users/User/Documents/FirstCode/Datasett/Wider_Face_Imdb')
    parser.add_argument('--zip', 'C:/Users/User/Documents/FirstCode/Datasett/Wider_Face',default='WIDER_train.zip')
    parser.add_argument('--mat', 'C:/Users/User/Documents/FirstCode/Datasett/Wider_Face',default='wider_face_split/wider_face_train.mat')
    parser.add_argument('--debug', action='store_true',help='just show the images')`